# pytest:mock a function from the file under test

Tags: python, pytest

Python version: 3.9.2

I am testing some functions from the main file of my code and it relies on another function defined somewhere else in the main file
like so

```
def func1():
    return "stuff"
def func2():
    if func1() == "stuff":
        do_stuff()
    else:
        do_other_stuff()
```

Now while testing i would like to test the func2() while mocking func1() so it returns
"not stuff" so i can test if do_other_stuff gets executed

I am doing it like this in the test file

```
@patch('main.do_other_stuff',return_value = None)
@patch('main.func1',return_value = "not stuff")
def test_func2(mock_func1,mock_do_other_stuff):
    main.func2()
    mock_do_other_stuff.assert_called_once()
```

Is there something i am doing wrong?
or something about the concept i fail to understand or a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I see that you are trying to format your code; but couldn't do it. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: So what makes you think it is not working? What is the current output if you try to run the test? It seems fine from your pseudocode.

Comment: @fooiey do_stuff() gets executed instead of do_other_stuff().
I verified this by adding prints in functions.
When run from the test file as main.func1() it returns the expected mocked output. But when print is added to func2() to see what was returned to it during the test it prints "stuff" instead of None